# Keypress to display string array jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, syntax, keypress

I have an array of string that I want to display one at a time on a keypress. I have an empty div  with the class of lyrics. Using

```
$(document).keyup(function(e){
    if (event.which==13)
    ...
```

I just am confused on the syntax here, how would I would specify this event print my array to my div. I left out most of my script here because this is the only part I need help with

Here is the HTML just a basic layout

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Rotating Messages</title>
    <link href="stylesheets/site.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var messages=[
            "Tonight I\'m gonna have myself a real good time",
            "I feel alive and the world it\'s turning inside out Yeah!",
            "I\'m floating around in ecstasy",
            "So don\'t stop me now don't stop me",
            "Cause I\'m having a good time having a good time",
            "I\'m a shooting star leaping through the skies",
            "Like a tiger defying the laws of gravity",
            "I\'m a racing car passing by like Lady Godiva",
            "I'm gonna go go go",
            "There\'s no stopping me"
        ];
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <header class="title">
            <h1> Fun with Arrays!</h1>
            <div class="lyrics"></div>
            ...
```

I just am confused how to use a keypress to print to an empty div

Comment: Post your html code too.

Comment: you are using `e` then use `e.which`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the messeges in a queue to display one string at a time.
The shift function lets you iterate over the messages array.

In the below example, after every time the user hits the enter key, a new line is appended to the div with class `lyrics`

```
var queue = messages;

$(document).keyup(function(e){
  if (e.which == 13) {
     var val = queue.shift(); 
     $(".lyrics").append(val); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  var i=0;
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
     var arrofobject = ["197","Damskie","198","M\u0119skie"];
     var len=arrofobject.length;
 if (e.which == 13) {
     if(i<=len)
     {
    $(".lyrics").append(arrofobject[i]);
         i=i+1;
     }
   }
});
```

Check [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wmqcd/33/)